# `Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy' Error

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm trying to apply a Lambda function to convert tensor values. I need to get the tensor values in numpy array. I'm trying `.numpy()` method but it gives `'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'` error. I added configurations for running the tensor functions eagerly but I'm not sure if it works in this case. And I simply create a Tensor constant and use `.numpy()` it works. What's wrong here?

The code that doesn't work:

```
tf.config.experimental_run_functions_eagerly(True)


def find_cluster(arr):
    print(arr.numpy())
    
FindCluster = keras.layers.core.Lambda(lambda x: find_cluster(x))

graph_input = Input(shape=(), dtype='string', name='graph_input')                           
x = FindCluster(graph_input)
m = Model(inputs=graph_input, outputs=x)
m.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', run_eagerly=True, metrics=['acc'])
```

The code below works:

```
tensor = tf.constant([[10,20], [30,40], [50,60]])
tensor_array = tensor.numpy()
```

NOTE: I need to use Python 3.6 so the latest tensorflow version available is 2.6.2 and I'm using tensorflow-gpu.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it's because when using Lambda layers, the tensors are executed in 'Graph' mode which is not 'Eager' so `.numpy()` function is not available. In order to retrieve a numpy object and work on it I used [.numpy_function()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/numpy_function) as below:

```
def find_cluster(arr):
    arr = arr.astype('str')
    
    print(arr)

FindCluster = keras.layers.core.Lambda(lambda x: tf.numpy_function(find_cluster,[x],'string'))
```